# No images/graphs appear after compiling an HTML notebook from R script

Tags: html, r, knitr

After compiling an HTML notebook from R script (done in Rstudio), I get an HTML notebook, but no images or graphs appear, except one graph that appears at the very end of the HTML document that is based on the last code. How can I solve this without updating the R version and Rstudio version (I have work restrictions)?

R version = 3.0.0; Rstudio version = 0.97.551

When I run my code in Rstudio, I have no problems producing graphs. But when I compile, no graphs.

Some warning messages that come up in the HTML notebook are the following:
""Warning in par("page"): "page" is not a graphical parameter""  [followed by]
""Warning in plot_snapshot(incomplete_plots): Please upgrade R to at least
version 3.0.2""

The following libraries are used in my script (copied from HTML notebook):

```
#Setup libraries first

library("openair")

#Warning: package 'openair' was built under R version 3.0.3
library("lattice")
Warning: package 'lattice' was built under R version 3.0.3
library("ggplot2")
Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.0.3
```

Here is an example of some of my script (it doesn't change much from this):

```
#Displays graphs for each day of the week. Best way to represent hourly data.

timeVariation (data, pollutant= "temp", xlab=c("Hour", "Hour", "Month", "Weekday"),
               ylab = expression("Temperature ("^o*"C)"), 
               main="Distribution of Hourly Temperature for 2012 to 2015", 
               name.pol="Temperature")
Warning in par("page"): "page" is not a graphical parameter
Warning in plot_snapshot(incomplete_plots): Please upgrade R to at least
version 3.0.2
### (B) ### Box Plot by Month and by Year based on Hourly Temperature Data from years 2012-2015 #######
data <- cutData(data,type= "month")
data <- cutData(data,type= "year")

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=month,y=temp)) + geom_boxplot(fill="grey") + 
  stat_boxplot(geom="errorbar", width=0.5)+
  ggtitle("Distribution of Hourly Temperature by Month (2012-2015)") + 
  xlab("") +
  ylab(expression("Temperature ( "^o*"C)")) + theme_bw()
Warning in par("page"): "page" is not a graphical parameter
Warning in plot_snapshot(incomplete_plots): Please upgrade R to at least
version 3.0.2
Warning in loop_apply(n, do.ply): Removed 291 rows containing non-finite
values (stat_boxplot).
Warning in loop_apply(n, do.ply): Removed 291 rows containing non-finite
values (stat_boxplot).
```

I have tried to solve this problem using online sources, but no success. Any thoughts on how to solve my problem? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: It is unlikely that you can because the packages probably do require the newer version of r. If the work restrictions are that you cannot install it or IT is non-responsive, you can try installing the version that you need in your temps folder(not the program folder) and limit permissions to your personal login. If you are on windows and your IT is as bad as ours  it will not ask for an administrator password...had to do this with iPython last week outside of this, you will have to find another package to publish the notebook to bypass the requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try your suggestion.